# three.js - webgl and canvas rendering performance issue

Tags: android, iphone, three.js, html5-canvas

I've created a 3d scene with below code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>3d Model using HTML5 and three.js</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: Monospace;
                background-color: #f0f0f0;
                margin: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <script src="three.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Curve.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="TubeGeometry.js" type="text/javascript"></script>      
        <script src="Stats.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Detector.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script>
        // variables
        var container, stats;

        var camera, scene, renderer, splineCamera, cameraHelper, cameraEye;

        var text, plane, tube, tubeMesh, parent;

        var targetRotation = 0;
        var targetRotationOnMouseDown = 0;

        var mouseX = 0;
        var mouseXOnMouseDown = 0;

        var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
        var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

        var binormal = new THREE.Vector3();
        var normal = new THREE.Vector3();



        init();                     
        animate();

        function init(){

            // container
            container = document.createElement( 'div' );
            document.body.appendChild( container );

            // info div
            info = document.createElement( 'div' );
            info.style.position = 'absolute';
            info.style.top = '10px';
            info.style.width = '100%';
            info.style.textAlign = 'center';
            //info.innerHTML = 'Drag to spin the cylinder<br/> You can identify cylinder face by clicking on it.</br>';         
            container.appendChild( info );

            // camera
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
            camera.position.set(30,10,10);
            //camera.up = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1, 1 );

            // scene            
            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            camera.lookAt(scene.position);

            // light            
            scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x404040 ) );
            light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
            light.position.set( 0, 1, 0 );
            scene.add( light );

            // CONTROLS
            controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );

            // Grid
            geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
            geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( - 500, 0, 0 ) );
            geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( 500, 0, 0 ) );

            for ( var i = 0; i <= 20; i ++ ) {

                line = new THREE.Line( geometry, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0x000000, opacity: 0.2 } ) );
                line.position.z = ( i * 50 ) - 500;
                scene.add( line );

                line = new THREE.Line( geometry, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0x000000, opacity: 0.2 } ) );
                line.position.x = ( i * 50 ) - 500;
                line.rotation.y = 90 * Math.PI / 180;
                scene.add( line );
            }

            // extrudePath, Helix Curve
            extrudePath = new THREE.SplineCurve3([
                                                new THREE.Vector3(0, 10, 10),
                                                new THREE.Vector3(10, 0, 10),
                                                new THREE.Vector3(10, 0, 0)
                                            ]);

            console.log(extrudePath);

            // Tube Geometry
            var segments = 50;
            var closed = false;
            var debug = true;
            var radiusSegments = 12;

            //alert('hello');                       
            var tube = new THREE.TubeGeometry(extrudePath, segments, 2, radiusSegments, closed, debug);

            // Tube Mesh
            tubeMesh = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject( tube, [
                new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
                    color: 0xff00ff,
                    opacity: tube.debug ? 0.2 : 0.8,
                    transparent: true
                }),
                new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                    color: 0x000000,
                    opacity: 0.5,
                    wireframe: true
            })]);

            parent = new THREE.Object3D();
            parent.position.y = 100;

            if ( tube.debug ) tubeMesh.add( tube.debug );
            //parent.add( tubeMesh );                   
            scene.add( tubeMesh );

            // projector
            projector = new THREE.Projector();

            // renderer
            //renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } ); 
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );               

            // stats
            stats = new Stats();
            stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
            stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
            container.appendChild( stats.domElement );

            document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'mouseover', onDocumentMouseOver, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'touchmove', onDocumentTouchMove, false );               

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

        }           

        function onWindowResize() {

            camera.left = window.innerWidth / - 2;
            camera.right = window.innerWidth / 2;
            camera.top = window.innerHeight / 2;
            camera.bottom = window.innerHeight / - 2;
            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            //camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        }

        function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {
            event.preventDefault();

            document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'mouseout', onDocumentMouseOut, false );

            mouseXOnMouseDown = event.clientX - windowHalfX;
            targetRotationOnMouseDown = targetRotation;         
        }

        function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

            mouseX = event.clientX - windowHalfX;

            targetRotation = targetRotationOnMouseDown + ( mouseX - mouseXOnMouseDown ) * 0.02;

        }

        function onDocumentMouseUp( event ) {

            document.removeEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
            document.removeEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false );
            document.removeEventListener( 'mouseout', onDocumentMouseOut, false );

        }

        function onDocumentMouseOut( event ) {

            document.removeEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
            document.removeEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false );
            document.removeEventListener( 'mouseout', onDocumentMouseOut, false );

        }

        function onDocumentMouseOver( event ) {

            document.removeEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
            document.removeEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false );
            document.removeEventListener( 'mouseout', onDocumentMouseOut, false );

        }

        function onDocumentTouchStart( event ) {

            if ( event.touches.length === 1 ) {

                event.preventDefault();

                mouseXOnMouseDown = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - windowHalfX;
                targetRotationOnMouseDown = targetRotation;

            }

        }

        function onDocumentTouchMove( event ) {
            if ( event.touches.length === 1 ) {
                event.preventDefault();
                mouseX = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - windowHalfX;
                targetRotation = targetRotationOnMouseDown + ( mouseX - mouseXOnMouseDown ) * 0.05;
            }
        }

        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            render();
            update();
        }

        function update()
        {
            controls.update();
            stats.update();
        }

        function render() {             
            tubeMesh.rotation.y += ( targetRotation - tubeMesh.rotation.y ) * 0.15;         
            camera.updateMatrixWorld();
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        }           

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now when I change rendering from WebGL to Canvas, the FPS drops down to 1-2 FPS from 56-57 FPS on mobile browser. Native browser does not display anything on page and in Opera page becomes too slow for operations. How do I make page operations fast with Canvas rendering or how do I enable webgl rendering on mobile browsers ?

Comment: I suspect because Canvas renderer does not utilise any hardware acceleration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

canvas renderer is software mode only, that means no GPU acceleration, the CPU has to do all the hard work that's why your fps drop.

AFAIK not every mobile browser is able to use webgl renderer yet, you could give opera mobile a try it's capable of webgl.

Answer (score 1):

One way to speed up canvas rendering is to reduce the number of segments used in TubeGeometry

Comment: I can reduce the number of segments but it makes some sense that number of segments is equal to the length of path. Please have a look on my another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767456/three-js-canvas-texture-on-tube-geometry-for-ipad)-@zz85