# three.js - canvas texture on tube geometry for ipad

Tags: javascript, json, ipad, html5-canvas, three.js

I've a 3d model of a tube geometry. There are 18000 co-ordinates on production side. I am taking every 9th co-ordinate so that actually plotting 9000 co-ordinates to build a tube geometry. I've to use `CanvasRenderer` only.

Now when I use `vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors` in `WebGLRenderer`, the model displays different color on each face. When I change it to `CanvasRenderer`, the model turns into white color only. Even I change `vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors`, the result is same.

Please find below the link of jsfiddle and link of my previous where mrdoob added support for `material.vertexColors = THREE.FaceColors` to CanvasRenderer.

[support for vertex color in canvas rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404618/highlight-cylinder-face-upon-selection-in-three-js)

[tube in canvas rendering](http://jsfiddle.net/RnFqz/20/)

Please find below the image to apply colors based on values.
[image: parameter values]

As shown in the image there are 12 values at 12 different degrees for every co-ordinate. So I've created a tube with radius segment of 12. Then I've stored these values into JSON file but as there 18000 points, the file becomes to heavy. Even though I am plotting 2000 points it takes too much time. For 2000 segments and each segment has 12 faces, there are 24000 faces on a tube.

Please find below the programming logic to apply color based on value of a parameter.

// get res values & apply color
            var lblSeg=0; var pntId; var d=0; var faceLength=tube.faces.length;
            var degrees = [ '30', '60', '90', '120', '150', '180', '210', '240', '270', '300', '330' ];
            var faces = tube.faces; var degreeCntr=0; var degreeProp;
            //console.log(faces);
            var res30=0,res60=0,res90=0,res120=0,res150=0,res180=0,res210=0,res240=0,res270=0,res300=0,res330=0;
            var res; var resDegree; var pnt=0;

```
                // fetching json data of resistivity values at different degree as                                                          //shown in the image
        var result = getResValue(); 


        for(var k=0; k<faceLength; k++){
            resDegree = degrees[degreeCntr];
            degreeProp = "r"+resDegree;

            res = result.resistivity[pnt][degreeProp];
            objects.push(result.resistivity[pnt]);              

            f = faces[k];               

            color = new THREE.Color( 0xffffff );

            if(res<5){                      
                color.setRGB( 197/255, 217/255, 241/255);
            }

            else if(res>=5 && res<50){                                                                          
                color.setRGB( 141/255, 180/255, 226/255);
            }

            else if(res>=50 && res<100){                                
                color.setRGB( 83/255, 141/255, 213/255);
            }

            else if(res>=100 && res<200){                               
                color.setRGB( 22, 54, 92);
            }

            else if(res>=200 && res<300){                           
                color.setRGB( 15/255,36/255,62/255);
            }

            else if(res>=300 && res<400){                               
                color.setRGB( 220/255, 230/255, 241/255);
            }

            else if(res>=400 && res<700){                               
                color.setRGB( 184/255, 204/255, 228/255);
            }

            else if(res>=700 && res<1200){                              
                color.setRGB( 149/255, 179/255, 215/255);
            }

            else if(res>=1200 && res<1500){                             
                color.setRGB( 54/255, 96/255, 146/255);
            }

            else if(res>=1700 && res<1800){                             
                color.setRGB( 36/255, 84/255, 98/255);
            }

            else if(res>1900){                              
                color.setRGB( 128/255, 128/255, 128/255);
            }

            for(var j=0;j<4;j++)
            {                   
                tube.vertices.push(f.centroid);
                vertexIndex = f[ faceIndices[ j ] ];    
                p = tube.vertices[ vertexIndex ];                   
                f.vertexColors[ j ] = color;                    
            }

            degreeCntr++;
            if(degreeCntr==10){
                degreeCntr=0;
            }
            if(k%12==0 && k!=0){
                pnt++;                  
            }
        }
```

This logic takes too much time to render the model and the model becomes too heavy and we can't perform other operations. The FPS on android drops at 2-3 FPS. Actually I've to render this model on iPad so have to use canvas renderer only.

So, how do I make this model lighter to load and works smoothly on iPad ? and is there any other way to apply colors on every face ? If canvas map as texture can be applied to make the model lighter, how do I build that map with all the colors based on value ?

**Update:**
After changing library version to r53, `vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors` and `face.color.setRGB( Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random())`, the model displays random color for each face on canvas rendering.

So now the issue is applying colors as per requirements (either by canvas map or any feasible solution) and to make the model lighter to load it smoothly on iPad.

Comment: The fiddle is running r.50. The change was r.52. Also, you will get more help if you ask _one question at a time_, and keep your example simple. This question will just make reader's eyes glaze over.

Comment: Ok I will change it to r.52. My question is on canvas map and so I explained the whole scenario as ultimately I've to render the model on canvas only.

Comment: How do I download the old version of three.js from github ? As latest version is r53. I can select it from tag but it does not show me the option to download the package of r52. - @WestLangley

Comment: Set "no library" and include it yourself. http://jsfiddle.net/RnFqz/21/ .

Comment: Here is one with face colors and canvas: http://jsfiddle.net/RnFqz/22/

Comment: After changing to r53, it supports `vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors`.- @WestLangley

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this will give you a little bit better performance + if you could come up with some automated method of calculating colors for each angle offset, that you could set hex color directly:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < tube.faces.length; i ++ ) {

    tube.faces[ i ].color.setHex( Math.random() * 0xffffff );

}
```

As I explained to you in the previous message - [three.js - text next to line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683727/three-js-text-next-to-line/), using canvas textures will only increase load to you fps if you'll attempt to render so many faces.

If you really want to render 24,000 faces on canvas renderer and still hope that it gonna show up good on an iPad – you are out of your mind!))

Here is the only solution that I can think of for now:

1)  Set your tube to only 1 segment.

2)  Create 12 canvas elements (for every radius segment) with Width equal to your tube length (see my link above).

3)  Now imagine that your 2000 segments you are going to create inside of each canvas. So, you divide your canvas length by 2000 and for every one of the portion of this division you set your calculated color!!! (Just like the Stats() FPS bar shows it’s bar, but you are going to have each bar different color).

4)  Then you just apply your colored-bars-canvas-texture to each one of your 12 radius segments and you are good to go!!

This way you’ll only get initial page load (calculating 'em 24,000 colored-bars) and YOUR WHOLE TUBE ONLY GONNA BE 12 FACES!!!

Now, I know your next question is going to be: How I'll pick my faces to show my lines with tag text?

Well, very simple! Just take current face  (1 of 12) pick position coordinates and translate them back to your JSON, just the same way you would do with 24,000 faces;)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for such great high performing logic. I've started with changing to r.53, segment=1 and 12 faces on canvas redering. But when I interact with tube, it disappears suddenly and appears again. What could be the reason ? -@Alex Under

Comment: "Create 12 canvas elements (for every radius segment) with Width equal to tube length." - how do I find tube length. Can you please explain this step in detail ?- @Alex Under

Comment: Please provide some example (JSFiddle?) of your what is going on with disappearing. Now, for the tube length - why don't you set it yourself so that your tube looks good on the scene (like it already does?) and so then you'll get your canvas width;)

Comment: can you please explain your logic [on this tube](http://jsfiddle.net/RnFqz/22/) ?- @Alex Under

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RnFqz/29/ - here is a way to go. I found some problems in my method. 1) You won't be able to deal with only 12 faces (because of canvas renderer). 2) You probably can't use tube geometry from path. I think the best way will be to combine 12 planes at 30deg angles. That way you can manipulate their texture maps, but not as it is right now. So take a look, tell me what you think.

Comment: If you can share your mail id, I will send you the code.-@Alex Under

Comment: you can write at an email from my web-site (that is listen under my profile)

Comment: I could not find an email under your profile and on your [website](http://qbizm.ru/en/).-@Alex Under

Comment: "For the benefit of others, why not accept this as the answer to your original question (since it is), and then post another more specific question in a new post? Add a live example if you can, so we can understand exactly what your additional requirements are."

Comment: you can write me at alex_under@live.com

Comment: Thank you Alex for sharing your mail id.-@Alex Under

Comment: I've sent you the demo.-@Alex Under

Comment: Ok, I'll check it in a minute

Comment: Did you find any feasible solution from the code I sent to you ?-@Alex Under

Comment: I've got my laptop stolen last week, so now I bought a MacBook, but it's going to take some time for me to configurate everything and get with you in touch again, so please be patient

Comment: Oh that's bad. Congratulations for MacBook and I will wait for the response from your side. Thanks.-@Alex Under